# Add Custom Shapes to MXGraph Toolbar

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am trying to add Custom shapes to a toolbar in MXGraph like it is shown in the examples for a toolbar. For exapmle: something like this:

```
addVertex('assets/displayResources/images/labelIcon.png', 60, 30, 'shape=displayLabel');
```

Now my own shape (in this case displayLabel) should be in the grid if u drag and drop it out of the toolbar. but it is always only the "default" shape that is visible.

I already registered my Shape like it is shown in the shape example:`mxCellRenderer.prototype.defaultShapes['displayLabel'] = mxDisplayLabel;`

I also tried different ways to call its style in the addVertex Method but it wont work. Even if i try the Boxshape that is shown in the "Shape" Example from mxgraph i only see the default shape...

EDIT: This is what i try at the moment:

```
    function BoxShape()
{
    mxCylinder.call(this);
};
mxUtils.extend(BoxShape, mxCylinder);
BoxShape.prototype.extrude = 10;
BoxShape.prototype.redrawPath = function(path, x, y, w, h, isForeground)
{
    var dy = this.extrude * this.scale;
    var dx = this.extrude * this.scale;
    if (isForeground)
    {
        path.moveTo(0, dy);
        path.lineTo(w - dx, dy);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.moveTo(w - dx, dy);
        path.lineTo(w - dx, h);
    }
    else
    {
        path.moveTo(0, dy);
        path.lineTo(dx, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, h - dy);
        path.lineTo(w - dx, h);
        path.lineTo(0, h);
        path.lineTo(0, dy);
        path.lineTo(dx, 0);
        path.close();
    }
};
mxCellRenderer.registerShape('box', BoxShape);

function creatingDisplayCreator(){
    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
            mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
    }else {
    var container = document.getElementById("graphContainer");

        mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);

        var model = new mxGraphModel();
        graph = new mxGraph(container, model);

        mxGraphHandler.prototype.scrollOnMove = false;

        graph.dropEnabled = true;
        var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

        var tbContainer = document.getElementById("tbContainer");

        var toolbar = new mxToolbar(tbContainer);
        toolbar.enabled = false;

        mxDragSource.prototype.getDropTarget = function (graph, x, y) {
            var cell = graph.getCellAt(x, y);

            if (!graph.isValidDropTarget(cell)) {
                 cell = null;
            }

            return cell;
        };
         var addVertex = function (icon, w, h, style) {
            var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
            vertex.setVertex(true);
            vertex.setConnectable(false);

            if(style=='shape=displayLabel'){
                vertex.value = 'label';
                graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR, 'transparent', [vertex]);
                graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR, 'transparent', [vertex]);
                graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE, 15, [vertex]);
            }
};
            addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
        };
        addVertex('a.png', 60, 30, 'shape=box');
        function addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, prototype, image) {
        var funct = function (graph, evt, cell) {
        graph.stopEditing(false);

        var pt = graph.getPointForEvent(evt);
        var vertex = graph.getModel().cloneCell(prototype);

        vertex.geometry.x = pt.x;
        vertex.geometry.y = pt.y;

        graph.setSelectionCells(graph.importCells([vertex], 0, 0, cell));
    }

    var img = toolbar.addMode(null, image, funct);
    mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct);
};
```

EDIT 2:
Now i was able to register my custom shapes, but further i got a Problem that says: "shape.initStyles()" is not a function if i drop a vertex in the grid. anyone know, where this came from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

Define shape like this

```
function BoxShape()
{
    mxCylinder.call(this);
};
mxUtils.extend(BoxShape, mxCylinder);
BoxShape.prototype.extrude = 10;
BoxShape.prototype.redrawPath = function(path, x, y, w, h, isForeground)
{
    var dy = this.extrude * this.scale;
    var dx = this.extrude * this.scale;
    if (isForeground)
    {
        path.moveTo(0, dy);
        path.lineTo(w - dx, dy);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.moveTo(w - dx, dy);
        path.lineTo(w - dx, h);
    }
    else
    {
        path.moveTo(0, dy);
        path.lineTo(dx, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, h - dy);
        path.lineTo(w - dx, h);
        path.lineTo(0, h);
        path.lineTo(0, dy);
        path.lineTo(dx, 0);
        path.close();
    }
};
mxCellRenderer.registerShape('box', BoxShape);
```

Then add shape to toolbar like this

```
addVertex('a.png', 320, 100, 'shape=box');
```

addVertex method:

```
var addVertex = function(icon, w, h, style)
{
    var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
    vertex.setVertex(true);

    var funct = function(graph, evt, cell)
    {
        graph.stopEditing(false);
        var pt = graph.getPointForEvent(evt);
        var vertex = graph.getModel().cloneCell(prototype);
        vertex.geometry.x = pt.x;
        vertex.geometry.y = pt.y;       
        graph.setSelectionCells(graph.importCells([vertex], 0, 0, cell));
    }

    // Creates the image which is used as the drag icon (preview)
    var img = toolbar.addMode(null, image, funct);
    mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct);
};
```

[Reference](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph-js/blob/master/javascript/examples/shape.html)

Comment: this is basically what i did, but i tried yours and it didn´t worked. Again i am only able to see the "default" shape i don´t see a box like it is designed in BoxShape, only a single rectangle.

Comment: Can you share your code, i guess you are globally setting the shape style of vertex somewhere which overrides the custom shape style.

Comment: I edited the question with the code. Its pretty similar to the examples given in the library or your example

Comment: For testing purpose, to check if your shapes are globally overridden add this line  `graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, 'ellipse', [vertex]);` before this line and check if ellipse shape appears.
`graph.setSelectionCells(graph.importCells([vertex], 0, 0, cell));`

Comment: i was able to register the boxshape now, but now i got a problem, that i can drop them on the grid and i get the error: "shape.initStyles()" even if it is a method in mxshape

Comment: You don't need to call initStyle(). You just have to register your shape and then insert a vertex with your shape name.
OR use this line  `graph.insertVertex(graph.getDefaultParent(), null, 'Hello World', vertex.geometry.x, vertex.geometry.y, vertex.geometry.width, vertex.geometry.height, vertex.style);` instead of  this line  `graph.setSelectionCells(graph.importCells([vertex], 0, 0, cell));`

Comment: i am not using "initStyles()" i am calling it like u wrote, but still got the error. I don´t know, where it is coming from

Answer (score 1):

here is one example to design on the custom shape ...

The custom shape here I have designed is STAR SHAPE.
--->
[Below link is the blueprint of shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmgrp.png)

---> below is the code

```
 mxUtils.extend(starShape, mxCylinder);
  function starShape() {
    mxShape.call(this);
    }
  starShape.prototype.redrawPath = function(path, x, y, w, h, isForeground) {
    // scale holds the shape what we design through out graph
  const dy = this.scale ;
  const dx =  this.scale;
  path.moveTo(w / 2 , 0 );
  path.lineTo(w , h / 1.3); // lower triangle
  path.lineTo( 0 , h / 1.3);
  path.moveTo( w / 2 , h);
  path.lineTo( 0 , dy / 3 + h / 4.2 );  // upper triangle
  path.lineTo( w , dy / 3 + h / 4.2 );
    };
  mxCellRenderer.registerShape('starShape', starShape);
```

---> [below is after adding color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9znfs.png)
       I hope this information helps